# My scrolling, while smooth usually, is jerky sometimes

Tags: swift, optimization, uiscrollview, nsdateformatter

The following is my code. I read using NSDateFormatters were expensive, but I'm not sure if that's what's eventually causing the problem.

Here's my code.

```
func tableViewOld(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    if cell.backgroundView == nil {
        cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(frame: cell.contentView.bounds)
        cell.backgroundView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
        cell.backgroundView?.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    }

    let backgroundImageView = cell.backgroundView as! UIImageView
    backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "nobg")
    var image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"goodbg")!
    cell.nopebutton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.nicebutton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.messageButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.mText.text = object.valueForKey("text") as? String
    let count = object.valueForKey("replies") as! Int
    cell.replies.text = "\(count)"
    cell.replies.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let point = object["location"] as! PFGeoPoint
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: point.latitude, longitude: point.longitude)

    let currentLocation = CLLocation(latitude: currLocation!.latitude, longitude: currLocation!.longitude)
    let distance = currentLocation.distanceFromLocation(location)

    if distance < 50 {
        // TODO: Fill
        cell.locationButton.text = "Nearby"
    } else {
        let distanceFormatter = MKDistanceFormatter()
        distanceFormatter.unitStyle = MKDistanceFormatterUnitStyle.Abbreviated

        cell.locationButton.text = distanceFormatter.stringFromDistance(distance) + " away"
    }

    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero


    let score = object.valueForKey("count") as! Int
    cell.count.text = "\(score)"
    if cell.count.text?.toInt() == 0
    {

        cell.messages.imageView?.image = UIImage(named:"0")
        cell.chatbubble.image = UIImage(named:"ch")
        cell.bg.image = UIImage(named: "regular")
        cell.locationButton.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell.mText.textColor = UIColor(red: 126.0/255, green: 126.0/255, blue: 126.0/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.nicebutton!.setImage(UIImage(named:"ups"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.nopebutton!.setImage(UIImage(named:"downs"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.count.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.time.textColor = UIColor(red: 52.0/255, green: 152.0/255, blue: 219.0/255, alpha: 1)
    }
            if cell.count.text?.toInt() > 0
    {
        cell.messages.imageView?.image = UIImage(named:"1")
        cell.chatbubble.image = UIImage(named:"chg")
        cell.bg.image = UIImage(named: "gtrl")
        cell.time.textColor = UIColor(red: 42.0/255, green: 204.0/255, blue: 113.0/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.locationButton.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell.mText.textColor = UIColor(red: 42.0/255, green: 204.0/255, blue: 113.0/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.count.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }



    if cell.count.text?.toInt() < 0
    {
        cell.messages.imageView?.image = UIImage(named:"-1")
        cell.bg.image = UIImage(named: "ntrl")
        cell.chatbubble.image = UIImage(named:"chr")
        cell.locationButton.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell.time.textColor =  UIColor(red: 231.0/255, green: 76.0/255, blue: 50.0/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.mText.textColor = UIColor(red: 231.0/255, green: 76.0/255, blue: 50.0/255, alpha: 1)
        cell.count.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    if cell.count.text?.toInt() >= 100
    {
        cell.messages.imageView?.image = UIImage(named:"100")
        cell.chatbubble.image = UIImage(named:"chb")
        cell.locationButton.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell.time.textColor = UIColor(red: 249.0/255, green: 194.0/255, blue: 65.0/255, alpha: 1)
    cell.mText.textColor = UIColor(red: 249.0/255, green: 194.0/255, blue: 65.0/255, alpha: 1)
    cell.bg.image = UIImage(named: "neutral")
    cell.count.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    if let dict : NSDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("userNiceNopeDictionary") as? NSDictionary {
        cell.nicebutton.enabled = true
        cell.nopebutton.enabled = true
        if let nice  = dict[object.objectId] as? Bool{
            if nice {
                cell.nicebutton.enabled = false
            }
            else {
                cell.nopebutton.enabled = false
            }
        }
    }
    if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {
        user["createdBy"] = user.username
        //user.saveInBackground()


    }
    let dateUpdated = object.createdAt as NSDate
    let dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormat.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    cell.time.text = (NSString(format: "%@", dateFormat.stringFromDate(dateUpdated)) as String) as String
    let replycnt = object.objectForKey("replies") as! Int



    if cell.count.text == "\(-10)"
    {
        object.deleteInBackground()
    }

    return cell

}
```

and I'm utilizing this extension.

```
extension NSDate
{
 func hour() -> Int
{
    //Get Hour
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour, fromDate: self)
    let hour = components.hour

    //Return Hour
    return hour
}


func minute() -> Int
{
    //Get Minute
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: self)
    let minute = components.minute

    //Return Minute
    return minute
}

func toShortTimeString() -> String
{
    //Get Short Time String
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
    let timeString = formatter.stringFromDate(self)

    //Return Short Time String
    return timeString
}
```

}

Is there a way I can optimize this? Again this isn't constantly laggy, it only happens sometimes, but in general it seems to be fine. I'd like to to ALWAYS be fine. Again I feel as though the NSDateFormatter might be the problem, but I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a hell of a lot in the cellForRow method. As a comparison my cellForRow method consists of around 5 lines of code. You should look at creating a custom cell class that removes a lot of that code. With a lot of code it just makes it harder to work out what the cause of problems is.

Each section of that code configures textfields could be a new function. Just, aim for like 10 lines of code per function. If you have more, move stuff into a new function (that makes sense).

What might be causing the issue is creating the `NSDateFormatter` every time you use the `toShortTimeString` method.

In fact, I've just seen that you are creating another `NSDateFormatter` yourself. Creating `NSDateFormatter` is an expensive thing to do. You should create one as a property of the `TableViewController` and use that over and over instead of creating it again and again.

That seems like it could be the issue but your function is too big to read through it all. Work on fixing that too.

Number of lines needed in the function... 3.

- 1 to dequeue the cell.
- 1 to call a function to configure the cell
- 1 to return the cell

Comment: I've been trying to do just that with the formatter, but I kept running into road blocks. I think at it's root, that's exactly what's causing the intermittent problem.

Comment: @JamesChen what sort of road blocks?

Comment: Just seen that you're accessing NSUserDefaults every time too but using the same key. May as well access it once and store the value.

Comment: I think that the problem is that I can't quite understand how to make these things optimal. I keep trying to use the NSDateFormatter once, but I get so many errors. It's all working now, but the problem is that as my user base increases, it becomes imperative to keep everything as optimal as possible